# Problema al compilar en React Next.js con error "node:buffer" y node-fetch

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, fetch, next.js, apollo

Estoy enfrentando un problema al intentar compilar mi aplicación React con Next.js. Al ejecutar con **npm run dev**, recibo el siguiente error:

```
node:buffer
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:buffer" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
```

Después de realizar algunas investigaciones, sospecho que el problema podría estar relacionado con la versión de node-fetch y otras dependencias. Aquí están las versiones de las herramientas y bibliotecas relevantes:

Node.js: v21.4.0
npm: 10.2.4
Next.js: 14.0.4

**Detalles del entorno:**

Versión de @apollo/client: 3.8.8
Versión de node-fetch: 3.3.2

**Configuración de package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "rpmcliente2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.8.8",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.6.10",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "yup": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4"
  }
}
```

Intenté degradar la versión de node-fetch a 2.x, pero el problema persiste.
Noté que si en el archivo apollo.js no uso fetch el problema no ocurre, pero lo necesito para seguir con la capacitación que estoy haciendo.

**Código de apollo.js**

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from "@apollo/client";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    link: new HttpLink({
        uri: 'http://localhost:4000/',
        fetch
    })
});

export default client;
```

La solución no tiene por que ser con estas versiones. Si me pueden ayudar compartiendo que versiones puedo utilizar para que me funcione mas que agradecido.
Intenté buscar en internet que versiones son compatibles pero no tuve mucho éxito por mi falta de experiencia.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo problema y tenía un proyecto.

Lo que hice fue instalar la versión @2.6.7 y se solucionó el error.

Espero te sirva.